# Properties of the YT Player Instance have changed?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Hoping to reach some YouTube engineers after following the advice of this page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/players/support

Previously, the YouTube Iframe API player Instance would have a property called `player.a` that would hold the reference to the DOM node. Now, it seems to have changed to `player.f`.

I was curious if this is intentional or not, and if I should expect this to be the new behavior.

I've attached a Codepen below reproducing this behavior. Please check the console output and the comments in the HTML as well for further details.

https://codepen.io/blakewilson/pen/yLNERMB?editors=1001

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide!

Comment: I think you should ask this question in an official Youtube forum. They don't provide support in third party pages.

Comment: try issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803

Comment: Thanks to you both, I'll give the Issue Tracker a shot.

Comment: For those interested, I've opened an issue on the IssueTracker. It can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/151858119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `player.getIframe()` to access the DOM node.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: After I opened that issue I figured there would be a public method that would do the job. Thanks a lot for your help!